# Why the %r0 of SPARC or MIPS, is always 0?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, sparc

I know that when you read %r0 in SPARC CPU (and MIPS), always return 0, but I like to know Why ?

What design decision is behind this and why ?

Comment: g0 or r0. I think it is g0 in SPARC!

Comment: in MIPS it's $zero or $0

Comment: It does not only appear in SPARC or MIPS but also common in many RISC architectures since zero is a very common value. In ARMv8 AArch64 mode, the register x31 is also hardwired to 0

Comment: @RahulTripathi: SPARC registers (by encoding in the instruction format) are `r0..r32` and `%g0` _is_ `r0`. Just in assembly language / mnemonics, they're "syntactically split" `%g0..%g7`, `%o0..%o7`, `%l0..%l7` and `%i0..%i7`. If you say `%r0` in SPARC assembly sources, you get `%g0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just the way the CPU was designed. Ensuring that `r0` is always set to zero is, for one thing, a way to avoid potentially costly memory accesses for a very common value.

On one hand (reading), it's handy to have a register set aside to contain the value of zero so that you can use it. Otherwise, you would have to load zero into a register yourself.

Many RISC processors tend to favour data manipulation in *registers,* accessing memory only for load and store operations. That's not a hard and fast rule of RISC, more of a tendency. Setting aside a register so that you always have zero available can be useful - it's a trade-off since you get one less register to use for general purpose values but the MIPS designers obviously thought it was worth it.

On the other hand (writing), because `r0` is tied to the value zero, you can put what you want in there and it will make no difference - it will remain at zero. That means you can use it as a target if you want to throw the value away.

Again, this has to do with the philosophy behind RISC. It tends to favour a very small number of instruction formats such as the MIPS `R`, `I` and `J` formats (register, immediate and jump). As an example, rather than having multiple instruction formats depending on whether you want to store the result or not, you can have one set which stores the result always, then just store it into `r0` if you don't care about it.

Hence, if you wanted to check if adding two registers would result in an overflow but didn't want to store the result anywhere, you could use:

```
add $0, $7, $8  ; r0 <- r7 + r8, but r0 remains at 0.
```

The MIPS documentation, `MIPS32 Architecture for Programmers Volume I: Introduction to the MIPS32 Architecture`, confirms the above:

> R0 is hard-wired to a value of zero, and can be used as the target register for any instruction whose result is to be discarded. R0 can also be used as a source when a zero value is needed.

Comment: I working in a RISC like cpu of 16 bits. I asked this, because I was thinking if in my case r0 being always zero, could be useful. In my case, setting a register to 0 value is cheap (a single instruction do it)); plus I only have a few instructions that uses 3 registers (load/store only), the ALU operation reuses one register as output (like ADD rd, rs -> rd += rs). I think that r0 being always zero, in my case is wasteful. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @paxdiablo: I think you meant to say `add $0, $7, $8`. The destination register comes first in MIPS.

Comment: I wouldnt say "philosophy behind RISC", it was simply a design decision, RISC has nothing to do with it you could just as easily have used another register and simply not saved or re-used the value.  By taking away r0 you lose a gpr, a heavy cost, so it is more of a burden not a savings as far as throwaway values.

Comment: @dwelch, I may not have been clear. The design philosophy suggests simplified instruction formats, not the use of a particular register as always-zero. That is, after all where reduced instruction set computing comes from.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand risc design, cisc design, etc.  I was just pointing out that r0 being read only, has nothing to do with cisc nor risc design.  It does support the overall MIPS instruction set design, not as RISC, but just as an instruction set.  No matter what instruction set you are using there will be times where you want to perform an instruction but discard the result, and for some of those the instruction set discards the result, or you burn a register, memory location, or other.

Comment: If MIPS didn't have a zero-register, they would have provided a mov-immediate instruction.  There's lots of opcode coding space for new `I` format instructions, isn't there?  So it would be like ARM, which has no zero-register: you just zero a register with `mov $reg, #0`, or any other 16-bit constant, instead of `addui` with `$0`.  With MIPS not having flags, the discard-write use-case is not a big deal either, just the trap on signed-overflow check.  (SPARC can just `sub` into the zero register for `cmp` so it's a nice RISCification, but MIPS needs compare-into-register instructions.)

Answer (score 1):

The main reason from instruction-set-design point of view is that the existance of a `/dev/null`-register allows for certain "condensing" of what otherwise would have to be *two* (or more) different instructions into a *single* one. Few examples:

- function `call` and `return`, using link registers, can be done with a single instruction:

  - As function call instruction: `jmp <tgtreg>,<pc>,<linkreg>`
    (SPARC `jmp` is an atomic `mov <pc>,<linkreg>; mov <tgtreg>,<pc>`), and
  - As function return instruction: `jmp <linkreg>,<nullreg>,<nullreg>`
- `cmp` or `tst` can be a simple `sub <a>,<b>,<nullreg>`

Complete tables of these can be found from Oracle's documentation, [SPARC synthetic instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1681/6m83631kp/index.html) and [sparcv9 synthetic instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1681/sparcv9-tbl-21/index.html); most of these involve `%g0` somewhere.

Comment: The zero-register is analogous to `/dev/zero`, not `/dev/null`.  Both discard writes, but `/dev/zero` reads as zero, while `/dev/null` reads as empty (i.e. can't read from it).  And BTW, MIPS doesn't have flags (instead using [compare-into-register instructions like `sltu dst, src1, src2`](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)), so `sub` with the zero reg as a destination only makes sense on CPUs with flags, [like SPARC](http://faculty.kutztown.edu/spiegel/CSc235/PowerPoint/FLAGS_AND_BRANCHING.HTML) or ARM.  But ARM doesn't have a zero-reg, and isn't nearly as RISCy.