# RISC-V NOP instruction

Tags: assembly, riscv, no-op

I am working on RISC-V 32I instructions recently. I got a question about `NOP` instruction, which the specification says it is equal to `ADDI x0, x0, 0`.

However, `x0` is not a general register which can be modified by the programmer. Thus, why `x0` serves as a destination register here for the `NOP` instruction?

Can anyone please shed some lights on this point?

Comment: x0 is a read-only register, that means every write to it is ignored.

Comment: just like MIPS or many other RISC architectures, writes to the zero register are discarded: [How does a zero register improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24646101/995714), [Is Zero Register 'zr' in aarch64 essentially ground?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52410521/995714), [Why the %r0 of SPARC or MIPS, is always 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19130790/995714)

Answer (score 7):

`NOP`  is a *pseudoinstruction* that expands to `ADDI x0, x0, 0`. The `x0` (or `zero`) is a *read-only* register dedicated to the value zero, i.e., it is *hardwired to zero* for every single bit. Whatever is written to this register is simply discarded since its value can't be modified.

From [*The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual Volume I: Unprivileged ISA*](https://riscv.org/wp-content/plugins/pdf-viewer/stable/web/viewer.html?file=https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/riscv-spec.pdf#page=36):

> The `NOP` instruction does not change any architecturally visible state, except for advancing the `pc` and incrementing any applicable performance counters.  `NOP` is encoded as `ADDI x0, x0, 0`.

Keeping in mind that RISC-V has no arithmetic flags (i.e., carry, overflow, zero, sign flags), any arithmetic operation whose *destination register* is `x0` will do as a *no operation* instruction regardless of the source registers since the net result will consist of advancing the *program counter* to the next instruction without changing any other relevant processor's state.

Answer (score 3):

oystercatcher quotes a correct statement, x0 holds the constant 0 and cannot be written to another value.

The instruction `ADDI x0, x0, 0` performs `x0 <- x0 + 0`, where 0 is an immediate encoded in the instruction. Such instruction has no effect on the state of RISCV and therefore is a NOP.

Other alternative for a `NOP` on RISCV : `ADDI x0, x1, 0` . Even `ADD x0, x1, x2` will have no effect on RISCV (there is no Carry flag on RISCV) and therefore behaves like a `NOP`.

Comment: Using `x1` as the source would introduce a false dependency that would stop the `nop` from executing until after the last instruction that wrote `x1`, if it wasn't special-cased by the hardware as a true `nop`.  Architecturally it's still of course a NOP but microarchitecturally it can be worse on a superscalar (and/or out-of-order) core.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/riscv/riscv-asm-manual/blob/master/riscv-asm.md

or on page109  of  https://riscv.org/specifications/

register x0    hard wired to zero

Comment: this is a correct statement, x0 holds the constant 0 and cannot be written to another value.